# h2o steam with python "accessing /pypredict."

Tags: h2o

I have tried the example under the steam/prediction-service-builder/examples/spam-detection-python , but get some error about
python:

```
This is an example of NOT SPAM
"Sorry din lock my keypad"

http://localhost:55001/pypredict?Sorry%20%20din%20lock%20my%20keypad
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
  <title>Error 406 1</title>
  </head>

  <body><h2>HTTP ERROR 406</h2>
    <p>Problem accessing /pypredict. Reason:
    <pre>    1</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i> 
    <br/>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is this  /pypredict in the "Problem accessing /pypredict." anyway?

Comment: Please post the full log. You only see the first line in the HTML result, and in this case it's not very informative. Your problem is probably caused by missing Python libraries, but to make sure that is the case we need to see the full log.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the tutorial locally, and everything is working correctly for me.

I built the example web service using `sh example-python.sh` rather than building the service using the web UI at `http://localhost:55000`.

Comment: Hi, I removed the questions from your answer. This kind of doubts must be solved using comments below the question. You must wait to have 50 points of reputation to be able to comment on any question. Now that you wrote somewhat of an answer, you can probably comment on the question.

Comment: But generally how should I test out my python code part?
My python code works fine with local I/0, but wrap it as
preprocess python code in the .war file, it shows errors 
that the python call not read in the test txt correctly.
thanks